# Why "ipse hic" is used here and not "ipse tu"?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, pronouns, agreement, demonstrative-pronoun

Lines 105–107 of chapter XXIV of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana* reads (emphasis mine):

> Cēterum facile tibi est frātrem tuum reprehendere, dum **ipse hīc** in mollī lectulō cubās. Tūne ipse semper bonus discipulus es?

In a Latin-Italian dictionary, I've read that the pronoun *ipse* can be used together with other pronouns in expressions such as *ego ipse*, *tu ipse*, *is* or *hic* or *iste* *ipse* to convey "me myself" or "me personally", "you yourself" or "you  personally", "he himself" or "he personally", "she herself", "she personally"... However, I don't understand why in the previous excerpt it's *ipse hīc*. What is the pronoun *hīc* referring to? Shouldn't it be *ipse tū* in the same way as in the next sentence *tū(ne) ipse* is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pronoun *ipse* refers to the implicit pronoun *tu*.
While *ipse* can be used with personal or other pronouns like you list, it is also often used on its own even when referring to actors that are referred to with those personal pronouns.
You could well insert a *tu* in that sentence but you need not.

The word *hic* is the adverb "here", not the pronoun "this", and is thus related to *in lectulo*.